# Detect failure in Code

Tags: java, junit, robotium

Can anyone help me with my problem?
I test my program with Robotium in Junit.

My problem is:

When I detect there is a failure in junit, how can I use code to detect there is failure in program? So, I can continue run if no error occur? e.g. if no error, continue testing, else exit.

Comment: Sorry, might be my sentence not clear enough. I mean, when i run the test, if failure occurred, will show red bar aside right, because i am doing research on testing method, so i need to run the test until failure is occurred, just like what i said,[ if 1st test not reveal failure, then will continue select other test case for testing, else if reveal failure, stop the testing. How can i write in code to know failure is detected.?

Answer (score 1):

> When I detect there is a failure in junit, how can I use code to detect there is failure in program? So, I can continue run if no error occur? e.g. if no error, continue testing, else exit.

This doesn't make much sense.  If you've got a failure in a JUnit test, that **means** there is a failure in your program.  If no failure occurs, the unit testing will proceed to the next test automatically.

---

But maybe you are asking if you can do this:

```
   // in some unit test
   assert(....);   // <<--- this test fails:
   // Do something so that the unit test will continue to the next assertion ...
   assert(....)
```

The answer is that you can't do that in any useful way:

- The unit test framework can only report unit test failures that indicate that they have failed by terminating with an exception.
- You *could* write a unit test to catch the exception that an `assert(...)` or `fail(...)` call throws and continue to the next assertion.  But that would destroy all evidence of the previous unit test failure.

So if you want to be able to do the second assertion despite the first one failing, you need to make them *separate* testcases.

---

You might also be asking if there is a way to get the JUnit test runner to abort on the first failed unit test.  The answer is yes that it is possible, but how you would do it would depend on the test runner you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Java's built-in assertions for your test. To create an assertion:

```
assert someBoolean : message;
```

For example:

```
assert (myValue == 3) : "myValue was " + myValue + ", should have been 3";
```

Assertions are disabled by default when running your program. To run your program with assertions, run it like this:

```
java -enableassertions MyClass
```

Then, if your program is running with this runtime option, whenever an assert is reached, the following happens:

1. If the boolean is true, the program will continue.
2. If it is false, an AssertionError is thrown with the specified message.

For example:

```
int myVar = 5;
assert (myVar == 3) : "myVar is " + myVar + " not 3";
```

results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: myVar is 5 not 3
```

IF assertions are enabled. **Remember**: all of that only happens when you enable asserts using `-enableassertions` or `-ea`. If you don't, the asserts are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can make assertions for a condition to be true or false-

```
assertTrue(soloObject.waitForActivity("Activity Name"));
```

Instead of wating for an activity you can use all the methods provided by robotium to make assertions example `isTextFound("text")`, `isTextFound("text")`, `isCheckBoxChecked(index)`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I not really clear, and can explain more or attach example.thx